# Проверить редирект

Tags: php

У меня на сайте есть форма, куда пользователь вставляет ссылку, и в некоторых случаях эта ссылка может перенаправлять на другую страницу.
Как проверить, имеется ли редирект, и при его наличии узнать конечную ссылку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделать запрос (например через curl), если статус 300, 301, 302, 303 или 307, то можно сделать вывод, что есть редирект. URL на который будет редирект можно получить из заголовка `Location` ответа.

p.s. редирект вполне может быть вложенный (в том числе циклический), по-этому возможно потребуется повторный запрос на полученный из `Location` URL, чтобы убедится, что он также не ведет на редирект + защита от циклических редиректов, чтобы не случился stackoverflow.

Comment: Что, если редирект средствами JS, по таймеру. Может, [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) или [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)?

Comment: @Sergiks в таком случае да, нужно какое-то решение способное запускать javascript код.